# UUID of Android and desktop app

Tags: c#, android, uuid, android-bluetooth

I am making two apps: one for PC (a server made with C# using 32feet lib), and another for Android (the client using Bluetooth adapter and socket).

I know how to make the connection between the two devices, but I don't know how to enter the UUID in the Android app and in the desktop app.

What must be entered in the UUID field on both the mobile and PC?

Comment: Is your project based on BLE?

Comment: no it is simple bluetooth communication not low energy